# context.getActivity() returns null in fragment after fragment is resumed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, onresume

When fragment is running, `context.getActivity()` is not `null` but when it turns to `onPause()` method and resumed back then `context.getActivity()` method returns `null`.

```
@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                                   ViewGroup container, 
                                   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.levelmission, container, false); 
  initComponents(view); 
  return view; 
}
```

Comment: shows us the relevant code

Comment: And indicate whether you use the support lib or not, and which version.

Comment: Are you use empty constructor for your fragment?

Comment: It might be null because the Fragment isn't attached to the Activity yet.

Comment: @Snicolas it's my lib android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: @jimpanzer    LoadMissionCallback mission = new HexPress_LevelMissions();    Here HexPress_LevelMissions() is Fragment and LoadMissionCallback is an interface.

Comment: Here i have attached it:    @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.levelmission, container, false); 
    initComponents(view);
    return view;
 }

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

you should reset your activity each time you recreate your view so something like :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.levelmission, container, false); 
 initComponents(view); 
 mActivity = getActivity();

 return view; 
}
```

then use mActivity instead of context.getActivity();

Comment: Using `setRetainInstance(true)` is like setting the `android:configChanges` property to deal with configuration changes. Using it for this purpose is a hack more than a solution.